# Move OctoberCMS website from Ubuntu VM to a CentOS 7 VM

Tags: move, octobercms, migrate

Our web developer picked OctoberCMS to develop our new website (his skill). Unfortunately before completion he rapidly left us due to health reasons and is no longer available. His Ubuntu environment has some problems and we need it on CentOS 7 anyway. The rest of us are OctoberCMS newbies, but want to learn it.

We built a CentOS 7 VM and installed OctoberCMS and want to move his work over.

We can not find any instructions on how to "export" the work he has done thus far and import it into our new OctoberCMS.

He is using 10 plugins and 3 he developed. (I don't know if that is relevant)

Is there an easy way to do this or at least instructions?
We have been googling, youtubing, IRC'ing for a week and still at a loss.
Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Well my suggestion for you is to hire freelancer from freelancing website like Upwork. Your task is not a small one and you would definitely need a expert into that

Comment: hey i can help you please contact me: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3076866/hardik-satasiya

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't anything special you need to know about moving an OctoberCMS install to a new server compared to moving over any other PHP application.

I am assuming you know how to do the basics of setting up a LAMP stack, such as setting up a virtual host for the domain you want to host the site on and setting up a MySQL database and user/password to access the database. There are of course many variants on how you could accomplish this such as using a management tool like Plesk or cPanel, or just configuring the services manually via the command line.

1) Ensure your new server is running at least roughly the same version of Apache, MySQL, and PHP.

2) Copy over the directory that contains all of the web files from the old server into the document root for your domain on the new server.

3) Do a database dump from the old server and copy it to the new server. If possible, use the same database name and username and password as the old server. This way you don't have to worry about updating the configuration of the website.

4) Pull up the site and troubleshoot any errors that come up. It is helpful if [OctoberCMS debug mode](https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/configuration#debug-mode) is on.

Following the above method will ensure that you have the exact same setup on your new server that the old server had. This will copy over all of the plugins, data, etc.

There are of course many complexities that can come up during a switch over like this, but this should at least get you started and you can come back to StackOverflow with some more specific hurdles.

Hope that helps.